# Find the constants $a,b,c$ such that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Find constants a, b, c so that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$,

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}\frac{a-2\cos(x)}{x} & x<0\\ bx+c & x\ge0\\ \end{cases} $$

My understanding:

For the function to be differentiable throughout it has to be continuous, hence $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{a-2\cos(x)}{x}$ has to exist and be equal to the right hand limit. For it to even exist, i concluded that $a=2$ so that the numerator will be rational so as for the limit to exist.(Do correct me if I am wrong on this).

I have also solved for the derivative of $f(x)$ which is $\frac{2x\sin(x)+2\cos(x)-2}{x^2}$ and after this I am completely unsure of how to proceed as the derivative at $x=0$ would be $0$

Comment: You said limit has to exist and be equal to right hand limit, try doing both for continuity and differentiability both will give you one more constant.

Comment: Actually differentiable function doesn't necessarily need to have continuous derivative but when right and left limits of derivative of our function exists it must be same by Darboux's Theorem. So you will do the continuity condition one more time for derivative of $f$

Comment: But that would give me $b$ and $c$ $=0$.. is that correct? @kingW3

Comment: You'd have $b=1$ since $\frac{2x\sin x}{x^2}\to 2$ while $\frac{2\cos x-2}{x^2}\to - 1$ as $x$ to $0$

Comment: "For it to even exist, i concluded that $a=2$ so that the numerator will be rational so as for the limit to exist.(Do correct me if I am wrong on this)." This isn't right, it isn't about rationality. For the limit to exist, $a$ must be $2$, this is true, but I don't see how rationality of the numerator justifies the fact.

Comment: How should I explain it then? @GitGud

Comment: Suppose $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{a-2\cos(x)}{x}\right)$ exists for some real number $a$. Now, $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{a-2\cos(x)}{x}\right)=\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{a-2+2-2\cos(x)}{x}\right)$ and $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2-2\cos(x)}{x}\right)$ exists. Since they both exist, you can subtract them to get an existing limit in this way: $\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{a-2+2-2\cos(x)}{x}\right)-\lim \limits_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{2-2\cos(x)}{x}\right)$. Can you finish from here? @SharminAeheli

Answer (score 1):

As stated in your question, we would require the left-hand limit of $f(x)$ at $0$ to equal to right-hand limit of $f(x)$ at $0$. Hence,
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^-} f(x) &= \lim_{x\to0^+} f(x) \\
\lim_{x\to0^-}\frac{2-2\cos x}{x} &= \lim_{x\to0^+} bx + c \\
\Rightarrow\, c &= 0
\end{align}

Also, we want the left-hand limit of difference quotient at $0$ to equal to right-hand limit of difference quotient at $0$ for $f(x)$ to be differentiable everywhere. So we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to0^-} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} &= \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} \\
\lim_{x\to0^-} \frac{2-2\cos x}{x^2} &= \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{bx}{x} \\
\Rightarrow\, b &= 1
\end{align}

$\therefore\, a=2,\, b=1,\, c=0$

Comment: Hi @Tham, how did you conclude that b=1?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{2-2\cos x}{x^2} = 1$ using L'Hôpital rule and $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{bx}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} b = b$